# Trouble parsing letters adjacent to operators with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse a simplified expression language with Parsec in Haskell to solve the [Tiny Three-Pass Compiler kata](http://www.codewars.com/kata/tiny-three-pass-compiler/train/haskell) on CodeWars. I'm running into issues where my parser won't parse correctly if there's no whitespace between an identifier and an operator; `a * a` parses to the complete expression, but `a*a` only yields the first `a`.

Stack script to demonstrate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-10.7 script

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Tok

langDef :: Tok.LanguageDef ()
langDef = Tok.LanguageDef
  { Tok.commentStart    = ""
  , Tok.commentEnd      = ""
  , Tok.commentLine     = ""
  , Tok.nestedComments  = False
  , Tok.identStart      = letter
  , Tok.identLetter     = letter
  , Tok.opStart         = oneOf "+-*/"
  , Tok.opLetter        = oneOf "+-*/"
  , Tok.reservedNames   = []
  , Tok.reservedOpNames = []
  , Tok.caseSensitive   = True
  }

lexer :: Tok.TokenParser ()
lexer = Tok.makeTokenParser langDef

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = Tok.identifier lexer

reserved :: String -> Parser ()
reserved = Tok.reserved lexer

data AST = Var String
         | Add AST AST
         | Sub AST AST
         | Mul AST AST
         | Div AST AST
         deriving (Eq, Show)

expression :: Parser AST
expression = term `chainl1` addSubOp

addSubOp :: Parser (AST -> AST -> AST)
addSubOp =  (reserved "+" >> return Add)
        <|> (reserved "-" >> return Sub)

term :: Parser AST
term = factor `chainl1` multDivOp

multDivOp :: Parser (AST -> AST -> AST)
multDivOp =  (reserved "*" >> return Mul)
         <|> (reserved "/" >> return Div)

factor :: Parser AST
factor = variable

variable :: Parser AST
variable = do
  varName <- identifier
  return $ Var varName

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a + a"
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a+a"
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a - a"
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a-a"
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a * a"
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a*a"
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a / a"
  putStrLn $ show $ parse expression "" "a/a"
```

Running this outputs:

```
$ ./AdjacentParseIssue.hs 
Right (Add (Var "a") (Var "a"))
Right (Var "a")
Right (Sub (Var "a") (Var "a"))
Right (Var "a")
Right (Mul (Var "a") (Var "a"))
Right (Var "a")
Right (Div (Var "a") (Var "a"))
Right (Var "a")
```

How can I write my parser so that both `a * a` and `a*a` parse to the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tok.reserved` is for identifiers. You should be using [`Tok.reservedOp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:reservedOp) when parsing operators. Consider changing the calls to `reserved` to call a similar function:

```hs
reservedOp :: String -> Parser ()
reservedOp = Tok.reservedOp lexer
```

**Edit**

To clarify what is happening under the hood, here is the implementation of `Tok.reserved`:

```hs
reserved name =
    lexeme $ try $
    do{ _ <- caseString name
      ; notFollowedBy (identLetter languageDef) <?> ("end of " ++ show name)
      }
```

Notice that `reserved` blindly accepts `name` without validating whether it is a valid operator or identifier, but that it stops if there are further valid identifier characters (otherwise `reserved "foo"` would yield incorrect results on a value of `fooBar`).

Since you specified that identifiers are any valid letters, `Tok.reserved` would halt when further letters were found, which is why `"*a"` failed.

`Tok.reservedOp` includes a similar restriction which short-circuits parsing when adjacent operator characters (from `opLetter`) are present. (e.g. otherwise you could mistake `**` (a common exponent expression) for `*`)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. Why does this work, is the lexing for identifiers and operators different?

Comment: I've made an update to the answer that should provide further clarity.